# After Installing FTP Service in Web Server(IIS),FTP Menu doesn't appearing in IIS Manager

Tags: azure, ftp, virtual-machine, iis-8, windows-server-2012-r2

In Azure VM (Windows Server 2012 R2), installed FTP Server(FTP Service) using Server Manger after installing ftp service FTP menu doesn't appearing in IIS manger. Again and again reinstalled FTP Server but same the issue occurring. Below i have attached snapshot for IIS Manager and FTP Installation.

[**IIS Manager:**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QKawd.jpg)

[**FTP Installation**:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yEbZM.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

1) Maybe obvious, but did you restart the VM?

2) When you click on the Sites tab, there should be Add FTP Site button.

If it does not work, try to install it again and add the Event Viewer errors if there are such.

Comment: I restarted the VM after FTP Service Installation. I installed several times but FTP Menu is not appear. 

In Event Viewer I got this Message:

**The description for Event ID 12 from source Microsoft-Windows-IIS-IISManager cannot be found. Either the component that raises this event is not installed on your local computer or the installation is corrupted. You can install or repair the component on the local computer

Comment: I tried to reproduce the issue and could not. I think it can be the intermittent issue and the simplest way would be to re-create the VM.